“Cannot find namespace 'google' error” occurs after running “npm run build”
I am integrating Google Maps into a Vue application.
According to the guide below there are three ways to integrate google Maps into an application.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api
Those three ways are
1,  Use dynamic library import
2, Use the NPM-js-api-loader package
3, Use the direct script loading tag
1 Using Dynamic Library import, it worked in development mode (when running npm run dev), but when trying to build (running npm run build), it's now showing these errors:
src/views/about-view.vue:288:14 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'.
288 let markers: google.maps.Marker[] = []
~~~~~~
src/views/about-view.vue:306:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
306     const mapInstance = new google.maps.Map(map.value, {
~~~~~~
src/views/about-view.vue:314:26 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
314       const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
~~~~~~
src/views/about-view.vue:458:25 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
458     marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)
~~~~~~
I am looking for help fixing these three errors.
I attempted to add a flag to ignore the errors but I was not successful and it did not seem like the right approach
The code is below:

<!— The code below is inside index.html —>
<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api-key&loading=async"></script>

<!— The code below is inside a template of the about-view component—>
<template>
    <div v-show="carouselIndex === 0" class="map" ref="map"></div>
</template>
<!— The code below is inside a script tag of the about-view component —>
<script setup lang="ts">
import Header from '../components/header-component.vue'
import UIDSComponent from '../components/uids-component.vue'
import UIDSData from '../data/uids-data.json'
import { onBeforeMount, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { UIDS } from '../models/uids'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
/* The 'route' object is used to navigate between the 'home-view' and 'about-view' pages.
  'uids' contains data related to the UIDS including details and locations.
  'carouselImages contains a string containing the image locations.
  'markers' is an array of location, and names of UIDS to be displayed on Google Maps
  'map' is the Google Map */
const route = useRoute()
const uids: UIDS[] = UIDSData as unknown as UIDS[]
let currentUIDS: UIDS | undefined = undefined
let carouselImages: string[] = []
let carouselIndex = ref(0)
let markers: google.maps.Marker[] = []
let map = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  if (currentUIDS?.existingLocations && map.value) {
    // disregard the line of code below 
    setHighlightImage(0)
    const mapInstance = new google.maps.Map(map.value, {
      zoom: currentUIDS.zoom,
      center: {
        lat: currentUIDS.initialLat,
        lng: currentUIDS.initialLng
      }
    })
    currentUIDS.existingLocations.forEach((location, index) => {
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: location.name,
        position: { lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng },
        map: mapInstance
      })
      markers.push(marker)
      marker.addListener('click', () => {
        setMainImage(++index)
      })
    })
  }
})

/**
 * Sets the marker to bounce.
 * @param {number} index - Index determines which marker bounces. 
 */
 const setMarkerBounce = (index: number) => {
  markers.forEach((marker) => {
    marker.setAnimation(null)
  })
  const marker = markers[index]
  if (marker) {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)
  }
}

2 Using  NPM-js-api-loader package did not remove the errors after performing “npm run build”.
3 Using the direct script loading tag did not remove the errors after performing rpm run build as well.
The attempts that sound right

Use dynamic library import,  Expected npm run build without errors.  Instead received the cannot find namespace 'google' errors.

Use the NPM-js-api-loader package.  Expected npm run build without errors.  Instead received the cannot find namespace 'google' errors.


The attempts that sound wrong

Use direct script loading tag.  Expected npm run build with out errors. Instead received the cannot find namespace 'google' errors.

Add flags to command to ignore errors (npm run build --force).   Expected npm run build with out errors.  Instead received the cannot find namespace 'google' errors.


Thank you

Could you please provide us with a sample application?

Thank you for the response.   I decided to use the vue-google-map library instead of the methods in the link (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api).  Here is a link to my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78679258/how-does-one-turn-on-and-off-marker-animation-for-vue-google-maps
