How does one turn on and off marker animation for vue-google-maps
How does one turn on and off a marker animation after the user clicks on a marker (for the library vue-google-maps)?
https://github.com/fawmi/vue-google-maps
This is what I have so far:
<template>
  <GMapMap
      :center="center"
      :zoom="7"
      map-type-id="terrain"
      style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
  >
      <GMapMarker
          :key="index"
          v-for="(marker, index) in markers"
          :position="marker.position"
          :clickable="true"
          :animation="marker.animation"
          @click="clickedMarker(index)"
      />
   </GMapMap>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
let center = { lat: 51.093048, lng: 6.842120 };
let markers = [{animation: 0, "position":{ lat: 51.093048, lng: 6.842120 }}];

const clickedMarker = (index: number) => {
  if (markers[index].animation === 0) {
    markers[index].animation = 1;
  } else {
    markers[index].animation = 0;
  }
};
</script>

Thank you
